# Android getDate returning wrong date

Tags: android, calendar

I have an Android App and I am facing a problem with getDate() method from Android's CalendarView only in Android M. I have tested it in 6.0- and it works like a charm.

The problem is: When user selects a date in my Calendar it returns only today.

It's my code:

```
CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.input_commitmentAdd_date);
commitmentItem.date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date(calendarView.getDate()));
```

My Calendar View:

```
    <CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/input_commitmentAdd_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/form_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/form_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_spacing" />
```

Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out. To fix that problem I just changed it:

```
CalendarView calendarView=(CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.input_commitmentAdd_date);
commitmentItem.date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date(calendarView.getDate()));
```

To:

```
  calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                                        int dayOfMonth) {
            int correctMonth = month + 1;
            date = String.valueOf(year + "-" + correctMonth + "-" + dayOfMonth);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. I had started to pull my hairs. (Just why getDate() not work like its written in Documentation... Returning today's date only... Totally illogical thing)

Comment: This started happening to me on Nougat. Frustrating

Answer (score -1):

```
    Calendarview cv=findviewbyid(R.id.cv);
    long selectedDateInMillis;
    long current = cv.getDate();
    if(current!=new Date().getTime())
    {
        selectedDateInMillis=new Date().getTime();
    }
```

Comment: Please explain how this solution works, how it is different from the original poster's (OP's) solution, and what is the essence of the mistake in the latter.

Comment: this solution works in case you want date/time in milliseconds from calendarview and caledarview giving wrong date.